# Disable keyboard input of ComboBox in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am working on a WinForms application that uses a combobox for selecting categories. This application is used on touch screens with a virtual keyboard. The devices will also be used outside in sunlight. This makes some colors seemingly merge together.

## Question

How do I create a non-text editable combobox that does not appear disabled?

### DropDownStyle: DropDown

**Problem:** Virtual Keyboard Displays

The ComboBox is displayed and the text can be edited. When the user clicks this on a touch screen device, the list is displayed, but the virtual keyboard displays. The keyboard then appears over top of the UI. (They have to close it each time they do it.)

### DropDownStyle: DropDownList

**Problem:** ComboBox appears disabled

This style works almost exactly how I want it to, except that the ComboBox is now gray. As stated previously, the devices are used in the sun and the gray makes it look disabled.

When adding the `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed`, I can change the colors of the ComboBox using `comboBox.BackColor`, but when the `DrawMode` is `OwnerDrawFixed`, all of the display bindings to the ComboBox are lost. The comboBox is set up using the following:

```
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Text";
comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

### DropDownStyle: Simple

**Problem:** This one doesn't work at all. (not even a dropdown)

[image: ComboBox previews]

*Disclaimer:* The arrow down buttons in the image is not my idea. I've tried to remove them and was told to add them back.

Comment: can you do something like this 
`private void comboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.KeyChar = (char)Keys.None;
}` seems pretty straight forward..

Comment: @DJKRAZE: This doesn't prevent the touch screen keyboard from showing up, it simply disables input. The combobox is also focused by default when the form loads.

Comment: `DropDownStyle: DropDownList` and `FlatStyle: Flat`

Comment: @valter This is a step closer, however I lose the border of the control. I'm looking into building a custom combobox at the moment as it seems the WinForms combobox is not very flexible.

Comment: Ok. If you bother to make a custom combobox why dont you try something simpler. Put a `label` on top of the compobox (only the drop down list will be visible) and handle the `enter, leave, down` events drawing the image and text you want (to match the compobox image).